# Is there a way to add Fraction slider to my GWT project

Tags: jquery, gwt

In my project i have to create a slideshow at homepage. I want it to be like the fractionslider [here](http://jacksbox.de/stuff/jquery-fractionslider/). Is there a way to add fractionslider to my dependencies list and use it with native query or just adding link/to/fractionslider.js to my  section and write simple jQuery fractionslider function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire/use GWT generated JavaScript from plain JavaScript and the other way around. Have you read: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html ?

Those are the basics. There are lots of projects that blend the two.

Comment: I have reviewed it. Thanks for the answer.